# Why cloud composer ( Airflow) hasn't run run yet as my schedule?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have created cloud composer ( Airflow) on GCC,    I have set a time schedule to run automatically on 28/10/22 at 05:00 UTC, but ***it hasn't run yet until now.***

***What is wrong with my environment configuration?   My airflow environment is kind of simple.***

let you take a look at the figure below, the figure shows time schedule and job on Airflow Web and Cloud composer console.  and the last part  is my airflow code, I fix starting date on code start_date_run=datetime.datetime(2022,10,28,5,0,0)

[image]

```
import datetime

import airflow
from airflow.providers.http.operators.http import SimpleHttpOperator
from airflow.operators import python_operator

import google.oauth2.id_token
import google.auth.transport.requests

from includes.bn_buy_sell_summary_py import  summarize_buy_sell_trans

#YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
start_date_run=datetime.datetime(2022,10,28,5,0,0)  # UTC Time , it is 12:00 at Bankok
XFunctionURL=airflow.models.Variable.get('function_url')

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Binance Trading Transaction',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date':start_date_run,
}

# for cloud function authentication cfn_crypto_trading_to_bq
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
audience = XFunctionURL
TOKEN = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(request, audience)

with airflow.DAG(
        'bn_trading_flow',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1)
) as dag:
   
        load_crypto_trading = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id= "crypto_trading_to_bq",
        method='POST',
        http_conn_id='cfn_crypto_trading_to_bq',
        data=({}),
        headers={'Authorization': f"Bearer {TOKEN}", "Content-Type": "application/json"},)
        
        summarize_buy_sell_transaction = python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id='summarize_buy_sell_trans',
        python_callable=summarize_buy_sell_trans,)
        
        load_crypto_trading >> summarize_buy_sell_transaction
```

Thank you for any support.
John Pongthorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [dag intervals](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#data-interval).

Dags always run at the end of their data interval.

Your dag didn't run at 5:00UTC because:

- Your start date is 2022-10-28@5:00UTC
- This creates a data interval of 2022-10-28 - 2022-10-29 @5:00UTC
- You created (or changed the scheduling of the dag), sometime on the 2022-10-28.

Fixing the start_date to 2022-10-28, and giving the dag a daily schedule means it will not run on the 28th. It creates a data interval using your schedule_interval.

What you wanted was the dag to run at 2022-10-28@5:00UTC.

Airflow [recommends](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/timezone.html) you use `pendulum` to define datetime objects, it's replaced the built in datetime module. This lets you define [timezone aware dags](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/timezone.html#time-zone-aware-dags).

- Set the start_date to `pendulum.yesterday()`
- Set the schedule interval to `0 5 * * *`
- Set `catchup=False`

This will always create a data interval for the previous day.

Lets look at a few examples with the new config above, say today=28th and yesterday=27th.

### scenario 1

- You create the dag today before 05:00UTC.
- The dag interval will be 2022-10-27 - 2022-10-28 @5:00UTC.
- The end of the dag interval has not passed.
- The dag will run at 05:00UTC on the 28th.

### scenario 2

- You create the dag today after 05:00UTC at 10:00UTC.
- The dag interval will be 2022-10-27 - 2022-10-28 @5:00UTC.
- The end of the dag interval has passed.
- As `catchup=False` - the dag will not run.
- Your dag will run at 05:00UTC on the 29th.

### scenario 3

- You create the dag today after 05:00UTC at 10:00UTC.
- You set `catchup=True`
- The dag interval will be 2022-10-27 - 2022-10-28 @5:00UTC.
- The end of the dag interval has passed.
- As `catchup=True` - the dag will run immediately, at 10:00UTC. This covers the previous data interval which failed to run.
- Your dag will run again at 05:00UTC on the 29th.

I would recommend you move `start_date` out of `default_args` and into the `dag` itself:

```
with airflow.DAG(
        'bn_trading_flow',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval="0 5 * * *",
        start_date=pendulum.yesterday(),
)
```

If all your tasks should be ran at the same time governed by the dag, don't define the `start_date` for individual tasks. Define it for the dag instead. (The airflow documentation & tutorial is poor when explaining this)